# Excel VBA - delete cell with time value less then

Tags: excel, vba, time

I'm trying to delete specific range based on a time value in the column "J" . So far I got this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim zakres As Range
Dim zakres2 As Range
Dim all As String
Dim all2 As Range
Dim ile As String
Dim czas As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set czas = wb.Worksheets("Dane").Range("J2")

ile = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Worksheets("Dane").Range("L:L"))

For i = 1 To ile
    If czas.Value < "00:01:00" Then
        Set zakres = czas.Offset(0, 0)
        Set zakres2 = czas.Offset(0, 2)
        all = zakres.Address & ":" & zakres2.Address
        Set all2 = Range(all)
        all2.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        Set czas = czas.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

In the line `If czas.Value < "00:01:00" Then` I'm getting the 424 run time error - Object required.
It confuses me, since the variable `czas` is already declared...

Any ideas why it's happening and how to deal with it ?

Comment: Not your current problem but you will want to loop backwards: `For i = ile To 1 Step -1`

Comment: try: `If czas.Value < TimeSerial(0,1,0) Then`

Comment: At a guess, I didn't test this though, you are deleting row 2 (or whatever row `czas` is currently) which is making `czas` invalid.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's true thanks for a tip, i'll check the 'TimeSerial' asap

Comment: @Warcupine the variable 'czas' is just to find the row with the time < 00:01:00, so after the code finds the specific row it extends the range to all2 with help of 'zakres' and 'zakres2', so 'czas' as a range doesn't change

Comment: But if you delete row 2, then `czas` will be a null range and have no property `.value`. It would change when you set `czas` to `czas.offset` so in that case if its now J3 and you delete row 3 again `czas` will be null.

Comment: @Warcupine so if a got this right, you suggest to duplicate the `Set czas = czas.Offset(1, 0)` and add in before the code deletes the row i.e 2 ?

Comment: That would work, not sure if that will give the results you desire in your routine though. Your best bet would be to create a unionized range and then delete everything after the loop.

Comment: @Warcupine how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the row that contains the range `czas` you also delete that range object. A null range has no property `.value` which is why you are getting an object required error.

A good way to mass delete range object is to use `union` to create non-contiguous ranges and then delete them all at once. This spares you the weirdness of shifting rows in a loop and also will significantly improve speed as deleting is pretty expensive.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim zakres As Range
Dim zakres2 As Range
Dim ile As String
Dim czas As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim delrng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set czas = wb.Worksheets("Dane").Range("J2")

ile = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Worksheets("Dane").Range("L:L"))

For i = 1 To ile
    If czas.Value < "00:01:00" Then
        Set zakres = czas.Offset(0, 0)
        Set zakres2 = czas.Offset(0, 2)
        If delrng Is Nothing Then
            Set delrng = Range(zakres, zakres2)
        Else
            Set delrng = Union(delrng, Range(zakres, zakres2))
        End If
    End If
    Set czas = czas.Offset(1, 0)
Next i
If Not delrng Is Nothing Then
    delrng.Delete
end if
```

Comment: Wow :D that's just awsome ! Thank you a lot !